# Any way to disable auto-detected language folders in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows, regional

I am porting a web app to Windows 8.1.
In doing so, I run into Error APPHOST9626, This reference causes failures when used outside of the debugging environment.

After researching, the reason this occurs is because the folder for some of my resources is named "ko" which the application builder misinterprets as being the korean language folder.

One solution is to rename the ko folder, but I would also have to rename all references to said ko folder and it would be a pain.

Is there any way to disable the ko folder being interpreted as the korean language folder?

Answer (score 1):

This what is found in [this sides](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e6dcf967-3bd2-4688-8367-a4f376095fef/language-specific-folders-in-wpf-project-build?forum=wpf)....it works for me !

> Hi, Issue is solved after removing all language folders from "\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend.NETFramework\v4.0\Libraries".
>   Thanks a lot :)
>   -- Happiness is only real when shared :)